# Is JavaScript good practice to always return statement/value?

Tags: javascript, syntax, coffeescript, return

I have started to learn and use  [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/) for several days and I am using the following [Coffee to JavaScript and JavaScript to Coffee](http://js2coffee.org/) converter as I am new in the CoffeScript syntax.

The converter above is perfectly "translating" the JavaScript to CoffeScript syntax, but I have recently needed to do the reverse. So, I have passed the following code in CoffeeScript to JavaScript converter functionality:

```
$(document).ready ->
  $('.b-date-picker').datepicker
    onSelect: (date) ->
      if $(this).attr('name').indexOf('gteq') > 0
        $(this).parent().next().find('input').datepicker 'option', 'minDate', date
      else
        $(this).parent().prev().find('input').datepicker 'option', 'maxDate', date
```

The result JavaScript was the same as the one I have passed initially to get CoffeScript syntax, except there was a *return* statement on almost every line:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  return $('.b-date-picker').datepicker({
    onSelect: function(date) {
      if ($(this).attr('name').indexOf('gteq') > 0) {
        return $(this).parent().next().find('input').datepicker('option', 'minDate', date);
      } else {
        return $(this).parent().prev().find('input').datepicker('option', 'maxDate', date);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

So, I have started to wonder why these *returns* are placed. Is this the correct JavaScript syntax that was set up in the converter too or maybe there is some kind of optimization/performance improvement?

Comment: not a good idea, never look at generated js too hard, it's like examining MSWord's HTML output...

Comment: Just fyi—if you decide you don't want CoffeeScript returning the last line, add a line after that says “return” and it will compile to nothing (and thus match your initial JavaScript).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CoffeeScript uses "functional syntax" in that *even statements act as expressions*. The resulting code is how it is emulated in JS (actually, a `return ?:` would be more precise, but this is a simpler transform).

Now, consider this CoffeeScript:

```
() ->
  if cond
    a()
    undefined
  else
    b()
    undefined
```

In this case, each branch maps to `return void 0` (read: `return undefined`) per the converter. A smarter converter *could* safely elided such return statement (that is, there needs not be any JS return statements to produce equivalent results), but it is not done in that tool.

Without such undefined value being the last expression evaluated, CoffeeScript *has no way of knowing* if the non-undefined result of the expression is *actually used* and must then *assume that the result of the function is used* which is why it adds in the return statements for every possible branch.

However, in a language (JS) without "functional syntax" (barring, say, function expressions), I'd say it's better to have an explicit return when needed; this shows intent .

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I think it clearly shows why the converter is working in this way.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to return a value from a JavaScript function.

The converter might be highly intelligent - and may have seen that the inner method call (to jQuery) returns a value (it returns the jQuery object) and that the value was otherwise unused - or it might be over-simplified or be implementing a particular practice.

Comment: I know that I do not need to return a value from JavaScript function. I just wondered is using "returns" a language standard or giving me some benefits. So, there is nothing useful in this syntax after all?

Comment: @gotqn it is definitely not a JavaScript best practice to always return a value. Return a value if you want the calling code to use the value.

Comment: @SteveFenton Thanks for clarifying this. As it is not a good practice, I am going to keep my writings as till now.